# Knockout ViewModel is being updated after ajax, but my foreach is not getting trigged

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I have a view model. Person is retrieved from an ajax call

```
 var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(persons, {});
 vm.Hobbies = ko.observableArray();
 // other vm objects
```

After the viewModel is loaded I display the page, now I want to load another part(hobbies) to the view model (working)

```
// ...ajax call...
 success: function(results){
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(results.hobbies, function(item) {
                    vm.Hobbies.push(item);
                    });
      debugger  
    }

// ...end ajax call...
```

On the debugger I can see that my Hobbies are now populated.

I have a view that is loaded in on page load

```
<!--ko if: $data.Hobbies-->
    <div>
      <ul class="fares-by-date-carousel" data-bind="foreach: Hobbies()">
            <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

At the start this portion does not load (as the expensive ajax call hasn't been called yet, which is fine)
but after the vm.Hobbies is populated the above html section still never displays.

not sure what I am missing

Comment: can you try changing `$data.Hobbies` to `$root.Hobbies`

Comment: ... thanks! that did the trick, I was on the wrong level of my scope

Comment: no problem, quick fixes are always good

Comment: Have posted a more complete version of my comment for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your usage of:

```
<!--ko if: $data.Hobbies-->
```

This should be used when you are scoping to a parent context that is being iterated over. For example you might to something like:

```
<!--ko foreach: Person -->
    <!--ko if: $data.Hobbies-->
```

In this example `$data` represents each `Person`, so the following `if` check will assess if each `Person` has a hobby.

If you are not using this structure (with no parent context) then you don't need to scope using `$data`, you can either use `$root` for the view model scope (which works even when nested) or leave it off all together. Both should work:

```
<!--ko if: $root.Hobbies-->

<!--ko if: Hobbies-->
```

### [Knockout Binding Context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

> **$parent** - This is the view model object in the parent context, the one
>   immediately outside the current context. In the root context, this is
>   undefined.
>
> **$root** - This is the main view model object in the root context, i.e.,
>   the topmost parent context. It’s usually the object that was passed to
>   ko.applyBindings. It is equivalent to $parents[$parents.length - 1].
>
> **$data** - This is the view model object in the current context. In the
>   root context, $data and $root are equivalent. Inside a nested binding
>   context, this parameter will be set to the current data item (e.g.,
>   inside a with: person binding, $data will be set to person). $data is
>   useful when you want to reference the viewmodel itself, rather than a
>   property on the viewmodel.